# Change status bar color and text color from coordinater swiftui

Tags: swiftui, statusbar

I'm trying to change the status bar color in the `WKScriptMessageHandler` coordinator, so that when I receive a message from the webview, it changes the status bar color. My problem is, is changing the status bar color and text color. Most solutions change it in the plist file or the `ContentView` file, which is not what I want. I'm using swiftui app, so I don't have a `SceneDelegate` file. I've tried using State variables to change it with if/else statement in contentView, but the coordinator couldn't access a variable inside of ContentView. Here's my code:

```
extension SwiftUiWebView.Coordinator: WKScriptMessageHandler {
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        if message.name == "iOSNative" {
            if let body = message.body as? [String: Any] {
                let function = body["function"] as! String
                switch function {
                case "changeStatusBarColor": // Recieves message from webview "changeStatusBarColor"
                // Changing status bar color code should go here
                default:
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven’t included any relevant View code, so it’s hard to say precisely how to do it, but why not pass Bindings to your coordinator for the colors?